# Pygame - rect disappears before I reach it

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to make a rectangle pop up when middle click is pressed, and stay popped up until I press left click in pygame.

Here is my code:

```
button1, button2, button3 = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
if button2 == True:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ((255, 0, 0)), (0, int(h/2), int(w/6), int(h/2)-40), 0)
pygame.display.update()
```

The thing is, when I press middle click, the rectangle appears, then disappears instantly.
I have tried putting it as `while button2 == 2:`, but the program hangs.

Thank you!!

Comment: The code is too short for me to understand. It would be nice if you could expand on your code

Comment: You are right. I should. I will post a new question.

Comment: More detailed question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527600/pygame-rect-appears-and-immediately-disappears)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to react to different mousebutton clicks, it's better to listen for the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` (or `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`) events instead of using `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`.

You want to change the *state* of your application when a mousebutton is pressed, so you have to keep track of that state. In this case, a single variable will do.

Here's a minimal complete example:

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
draw_rect = False
rect = pygame.rect.Rect((100, 100, 50, 50))
while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if e.button == 2:
                draw_rect = True
            elif e.button == 1:
                draw_rect = False

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    if draw_rect:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), rect, 2)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
button1, button2, button3 = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
if button2 == True:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ((255, 0, 0)), (0, int(h/2), int(w/6), int(h/2)-40), 0)
pygame.display.update()
```

to

```
button1, button2, button3 = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
if button2 == True:
      rect_blit=True
pygame.display.update()
```

then have

```
if rect_blit==True:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ((255, 0, 0)), (0, int(h/2), int(w/6), int(h/2)-40), 0)
```

somewhere in your main loop (before `pygame.display.update`).

Another thing is that you do not need to say `if some_variable == True:`. Instead you can just say `if some_variable:`. They do the exact same thing.