# Pygame - rect appears and immediately disappears

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am rewriting my question 
[Pygame - rect disappears before I reach it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506991/pygame-rect-disappears-before-i-reach-it) because I think I have not described it clearly.

Full code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pygame, time, sys, random, os
from pygame.locals import *
from time import gmtime, strftime

pygame.init()

w = 640
h = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h),RESIZABLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = y = 100

def starting():
    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
    text = basicfont.render('Starting...', True, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255))
    textrect = text.get_rect()
    textrect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    textrect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
    screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
    screen.blit(text, textrect)
    pygame.display.update()

def taskbar():
    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ((0, 255, 0)), (0, h-40, w, 40), 0)
    text = basicfont.render(strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime()), True, (0, 0, 0))
    text2 = basicfont.render(strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()), True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text, (w - 100, h - 37))
    screen.blit(text2, (w - 100, h - 17))
    logoimage = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\chef\Desktop\logo.png").convert()
    logoimage = pygame.transform.scale(logoimage, (40, 40))
    screen.blit(logoimage, (0, h-40),)

def start():
    button1, button2, button3 = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if 0 < mousex < 40 and h-40 < mousey < h:
        if button1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, ((255, 0, 0)), (0, int(h/2), int(w/6), int(h/2)-40), 0)
    pygame.display.update()

starting()
#time.sleep(2)

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()  
        elif event.type==VIDEORESIZE:
            w = event.dict['size'][0]
            h = event.dict['size'][1]
            screen=pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'],RESIZABLE)
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    taskbar()
    start()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Just like my original question, when I press logoimage.png and the red rectangle pops up, it shows for a second then immediately disappears. How can I make it so that the rect will stay until I press outside of it?

Comment: You should **edit the previous question**, not ask a new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame - rect disappears before I reach it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506991/pygame-rect-disappears-before-i-reach-it)

Comment: @JosepValls I know it is a duplicate of my original question, i just asked a new one because I thought a new question would be better than editing my old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `screen.fill((255, 255, 255))` out of the `while` loop. This is causing problems, because each time the program loops, it colors the display white, writing over whatever you had there before. One way to work around this is to move the `screen.fill((255, 255, 255))` out of the loop and place it before the `pygame.draw.rect` function. This will color the screen before you place the rect, and will not continue to fill it. For instance:

```
if button1:
            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, ((255, 0, 0)), (0, int(h/2), int(w/6), int(h/2)-40), 0)
```

You could also move it elsewhere or come up with a way to draw rect every loop after you fill the window.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flag a boolean that it's been clicked. Something like:

```
btnClicked = false

def start():
    button1, button2, button3 = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if button1:
        if 0 < mousex < 40 and h-40 < mousey < h:
            btnClicked = true
        else:
            btnClicked = false

    if btnClicked:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ((255, 0, 0)), (0, int(h/2), int(w/6), int(h/2)-40), 0)
    pygame.display.update()
```